# Как правильно написать?

Tags: грамматика

экономить на рекламе увеличивая продажи

Answer (score 1):

экономить на рекламе, увеличивая продажи

Comment: Всё-таки запятая, а не дефис?

Comment: Дефис здесь неуместен, ведь "увеличивая продажи" - это деепричастный оборот

Answer (score 0):

Если хочется тире (не дефис), можно изменить фразу. Экономить на рекламе - увеличивать продажи. Но тогда несколько поменяется смысл.